# Snap SVG dragging and scaling: My rectangle won't stop scaling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm quite new to Snap.svg, and I've been trying to make a rectangle that can be moved and resized using the mouse. I used Snap.svg element.drag(); to do the moving around, and I used this tutorial for the scaling:
http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-dragscale

You can drag it around by clicking & holding. To scale, you double-click on the rect once, and then you drag. My problem is that it moves around just fine, until I decide to resize it. When I do, it never gets out of scaling mode, and I can never go back to moving it around again. I tried fiddling with the code but couldn't get it right. How can I get it to stop scaling after another double-click? Thanks for reading!

This is my javascript code:

```
                      createRect();
                      function createRect(){
                        var r = Snap('#svg');
                        var newRect = r.rect(100,100,80,60);
                        newRect.attr({                            
                            fill:'#afe5ff',
                            stroke:'#000',
                            strokeWidth: 2
                        });   


                         newRect.dblclick( addHandleFunc );

                         var dragging = 0;
                         var handleGroup;

                         function addHandleFunc() {
                            if( dragging === 0 ) {
                                dragging = 1;
                                var bb = this.getBBox();                                    
                                this.drag(move,start,stop);


                            } else {

                                dragging = 0;                                    
                                r.append(this);    

                              }             


                        }

                        function start() {
                        this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local);
                        }

                        function move(dx,dy) {
                             var scale = 1 + dx / 50;
                             this.attr({
                             transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "S" : "s") + scale                                 
                             });

                        }

                        function stop() {}

                        newRect.drag(); 

                      }
```

And an [example](https://jsbin.com/tucudixoju/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the second double-click, you need to "turn off" the scaling mode by resetting the drag functions to the default ones.  To do that, just call `drag()` again with no parameters.

```
if ( dragging === 0 ) {
  dragging = 1;
  var bb = this.getBBox();                                    
  this.drag(move,start,stop);
} else {
  dragging = 0;                                    
  this.undrag();
  this.drag();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the help! I tried this and it works, however it only allows me to resize it just once, and then it does not work again. After using some printing I see that even after calling the drag(); with default arguments, it still uses the functions start, move, stop. Why is this happening?

https://jsbin.com/qipejuduko/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it properly. Deregister the scaling version of the drag handlers by calling `undrag()` first.